# Display only selected columns

Tags: c#, linq

suppose that I have this List of Employees representing a table of employees.

```
  public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string Function { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }



        public static List<Employee> GetEmployeesList()
        {
            return new List<Employee>() {
                    new Employee() { EntryDate = new DateTime(2011, 05, 01), Name = "Fons",  Department = "Finance", Function = "Trader", Salary = 6500 },
                    new Employee() { EntryDate = new DateTime(2013, 05, 02), Name = "Mary",  Department = "Finance", Function = "BusinessAnalyst", Salary = 2500 },
                    new Employee() { EntryDate = new DateTime(2012, 04, 03), Name = "Alex",  Department = "Finance", Function = "Trader", Salary = 2100 },
                    new Employee() { EntryDate = new DateTime(2013, 05, 04), Name = "Jim",   Department = "R&D", Function = "Trainer", Salary = 3300 },
                    new Employee() { EntryDate = new DateTime(2010, 06, 05), Name = "Ellen", Department = "Dev", Function = "Developer", Salary = 2500 },
                    new Employee() { EntryDate = new DateTime(2000, 09, 06), Name = "Mike",  Department = "Dev", Function = "Consultant", Salary = 5100 },
                    new Employee() { EntryDate = new DateTime(1999, 03, 07), Name = "Jack",  Department = "R&D", Function = "Developer", Salary = 6100 },
                    new Employee() { EntryDate = new DateTime(1989, 01, 08), Name = "Demy",  Department = "Dev", Function = "Consultant", Salary = 3300 }};
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to select only desired columns to be displayed.
Someting like :

```
   public static List<Employee> SelectColumnsFromTable(List<Employee> employees, int[] selectedColumns)
    {
        // only select colums 1, 3 and 4            
    }
```

I have seen that it is possible with SQL and GridView, but in my case, the result will be printed on the console.
Is it possible using C# and Linq ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question, it is important to select specific properties of a class based on their index. If the relevant indices are provided to you by the user, you can use reflection to access the properties dynamically. The key points are [Type.GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [PropertyInfo.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I've put together a small [sample](http://ideone.com/e.js/rYx2Pa) to demonstrate:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Employee
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName { get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}

public class Test
{
    private static string[] GetColumnValues(Employee emp, params int[] cols)
    {
        var props = emp.GetType().GetProperties();
        var values = new List<string>();
        foreach(var i in cols)
        {
            if (i >= 0 && i < props.Length)
            {
                object value = props[i].GetValue(emp, null);
                values.Add(value == null ? string.Empty : value.ToString());
            }
        }
        return values.ToArray();
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        var emp = new Employee() { Id = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" };
        var values = GetColumnValues(emp, 0, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", values));
    }
}
```

Please note that referencing the properties by their index might not be very deterministic of you change the implementation later on. So selecting by the property's name might be more stable. Also, the column selector function GetColumnValues does not return Employees, but the values as a string array so you can use it in String.Join. You can use the function in Linq:

```
var rows = from x in listOfEmps select GetColumnValues(x, 0, 2);
foreach(var row in rows)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", row));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = (from i in v.db.DatabaseName
            orderby i.EmpID descending
            select new {i.Name, i.Function,i.Salary}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(row => (int)row["demoid"] > 5)//your condition here
             .Select(row => new
              {
                 demoid = Convert.ToInt32(row["demoid"]),
                 demoname = row["demoname"] != null ? 
                            row["demoname"].ToString() : 
                            String.Empty
              }).ToList();
```

Or you can define class:

```
public class myClass
{
  public int demoid;
  public string demoname;
}
```

and then:

```
List<myClass> list = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(row => (int)row["demoid"] > 5)
             .Select(row => new myClass
             {
                 demoid = Convert.ToInt32(row["demoid"]),
                 demoname = row["demoname"] != null ? 
                            row["demoname"].ToString() : 
                            String.Empty
             }).ToList<myClass>();
```

this is selecting a particular value to a list. However you can use `IList<myClass> classcollection= new List<myClass>();` and then add the particular list to class1 based on condition.
Note: here class collection can hold multiple list as u want the columns 1,3,4